# Teclado movil desordena / no deja ver secciones del sitio web

Tags: html, css, formularios, teclado

al seleccionar un campo del formulario de contacto, desde un dispositivo movil, se despliega el teclado y desordena el diseño:

Formulario sin seleccionar ningun campo:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Luego de seleccionar el campo "nombre":
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

(La sección anterior se superpone en el formulario y no deja ver lo que se escribe).

Al presionar la tecla "atras" (para que el teclado se oculte) salta a una parte de la sección anterior:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Les dejo el codigo en 2 pastebin para no extender la pregunta:

HTML: https://pastebin.com/djWq0gfN
CSS: https://pastebin.com/tuuXVxnK
URL del sitio: http://alpasoaventura.com/

Gracias!

Comment: Aun no puedo solucionar el problema, alguna idea?